# Mysql JSON - Retrieve the object (or just a key/pair) where key/value equals foo

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm using Mysql 5.7 and I have a column `cars` with values like this:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "model": "bar"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "model": "foo"
   }
]
```

I need the id (or the all object) where `model = 'foo'`, expected: `2`.

I already tried this:

Query:

```
select JSON_SEARCH(cars, "one", 'foo', NULL, '$[*].model') 
from orders;
```

Output:

```
$[1].model
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found out after a bit:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(cars->>'$[*].id', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(cars->>'$[*].model', "one", 'foo', NULL, '$'))) as foo from users;
```

Output: `2`